# How to say "I hurt when she is laugh"?

Tags: conditional-constructions, conjugations

> Once upon she's laugh, that times I hurt.

Is that sentence right for describe: "I hurt when she is laugh" ?

Comment: Could you please say if this action is in the past. And if you want to say that **you feel sad when she laughs (at you?)**, or if **it (physically) hurts when you laugh a lot**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Once upon** she's laugh, that times **I hurt**

That sentence is not grammatical, and it is quite difficult to understand what you are trying to say, there are several possibilities.

When we tell a funny or sad story that happened in the past we might say

> 1. [Did I tell you about the time] *she once **laughed*** so hard, she hurt herself [?]
> 2. She once *laughed* so hard, she ***was bent double***.
> 3. She *laughed* so much, her ***stomach hurt***.

Sentences 1, 2 and 3 express a moment of hilarity, a time when someone said something so funny that they laughed, and laughed until tears were streaming down their face, or they couldn't catch their breath.

If both of you were laughing then say

> 4. She said something funny that ***made me laugh*** so hard *it hurt*.
> 5. **We laughed** so hard *it hurt*.
> 6. We were laughing so hard, our ***stomachs ached***

But if you want to say her laughter *hurt your feelings* then say

> 7. She **hurt my feelings** when she laughed (at me).
> 8. My **feelings were hurt** when she laughed (at me)

Answer (score 5):

> Once upon she's laugh, that times I hurt.

This is not grammatical.

The correct phrase is “once upon a time”, not “once upon”. This phrase means a long time in the past.  You use this phrase when you begin telling a story. For example: “Once upon a time there was a king.”

Second, when you use the word *laugh* as a verb, you don't use a helping verb (is, are, am, was, were, etc.) before the first form of a verb (*laugh* in this case). Also, you should add an ‘s’ to *laugh* because the subject (she)  is a  third person singular pronoun.  As far as I understand, you want to say as follows:

- I hurt her when she laughs. (in the present simple)
- I hurt her when she laughed (in the past simple).

If you want to put emphasis on the time she laughs or laughed, you can say:

- I hurt her whenever she laughs.
- I hurt her whenever she laughed.

However, if her laughing hurts your feelings, You should say:

- It hurts me when she laughs.
- It hurt me when she laughed.

Comment: Agreed that the meaning of the original sentence is unclear, but your version is very different from how I interpret the original.You're saying that 1. *"He hits (physical hurt) her when she laughs"* or 2. *"He hurts (her feelings) when she laughs"*

Comment: @Mari-LouA, your edit is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Not even close. What you want to say is:

> I hurt when she laughs.

or:

> Whenever she laughs, I hurt.

If you wanted to use the verb *is*, you could say:

> I hurt when she is laughing.

Or:

> Whenever she’s laughing, it hurts me.

Comment: I was wondering if the OP said "Once upon" and "that times" to express the time (in the past) he laughed so hard it hurt. As in "*Once she made me laugh so much, it hurt.*"

Comment: You are more confident than I am in what the OP intends by _"I hurt when she is laugh."_ Does he mean "she thinks it is funny when I am hurt" or "her laughter hurts me"?

Comment: Both commenters are right that I am making assumptions about the intended meaning here, and that other valid interpretations also exist. Perhaps more than one answer needs to be written, @Mari-LouA.

Answer (score 0):

**I hurt** has another meaning which is I **caused a physical injury to her or to myself**.
 **I was hurt** when she laughed at me means that **you were emotionally hurt** when she laughed at you, but still this sentence is unnatural too. **It hurt me** when she laughed at me, is acceptable and natural or native-like sentence.
 **Once upon a time** is used in the beginning of a **story,**. Generally, the time used in stories is the **past tense**. **Once upon a time**, It hurt me when she laughed at me. In fact, this sentence does not fit as a beginning of a story since it is a description of an event that may happen **daily** to anyone. You can say instead`: **At that time, when she laughed at me, it hurt me.** or **My feelings were hurt when she laughed at me at that time.** 
You should specify  the **time** of the event.